# Object.keys() vs Array.prototype.keys()

Tags: javascript

```
let arr = new Array(3)
console.log(Object.keys(arr)) // []
console.log([...arr.keys()]) // [0,1,2]
```

Why is there a difference? It seems that an array in javascript can simultaneously have a length of 3 and be empty. How do you know the behavior of the different functions that operate on sparse lists?

Comment: "How do you know the behavior..."  At the risk of sounding snarky: reading documentation on each method: [A](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [B](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys)

Comment: @Thomas: If the question indeed is "how do you know behavior of functions", then the answer is "by reading the documentation". If you are interested in arrays, there is no difference between normal and sparse array, both are just arrays to javascript, and it is just fine to create an array of any length while leaving the fields blank. Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: @Amy where in that documentation explains the behavior demonstrated?

Comment: @Thomas It's mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys#key_iterator_doesnt_ignore_holes) in the `Array.prototype.keys` page that *"Key iterator doesn't ignore holes"*. `new Array(3)` creates an array of holes. But, that can be confusing. It's a fair question.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys()` does [expect the parameter to be of type `object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#parameters) and will cast [anything else implicitly to one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#non-object_coercion). Passing an empty array will be casted to an empty object I guess: `Object.assign({}, new Array(3))` will give `{}`